# Check if body tag hass class and apply css for certain class in media query

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if body tag has certain class and then apply some css to other class, but only if screen is small (in media query)?
My body tag changes classes thry javascript and hass either class="menu" or class="menu menu-open".Now if screen is max-width:640px and class="menu" I need to add css for class="logo" (display: table, margin: 0 auto).
How can I do that?

Comment: Simply use the descendant selector to format your logo element depending on the body class (`body.foo .logo { … }`) – and wrap that into whatever media queries you need it to be applied for.

Comment: please rephrase your question, i am confused what you are asking for

Comment: Rule is: if body hass class menu when screen size is less then 640 then apply css for class logo display table,margin:0 auto...in any other case class logo remains display inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your 'logo' is inside the `body`, I think your asking to apply a rule when the body has `menu` but **doesn't** have `menu-open` in the class list:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
    body.menu:not(.menu-open) .logo {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: True. I can't really tell exactly what is being asked. If the goal is to NOT apply the style IF it has .menu-open, then this seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    body.menu .logo {
        display: table;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it with jQuery.
You can chack the window width and body class,  like so:

```
var bodyTag = $('body');
var logo = $('.logo');
if($(window).width() < 640 && $(bodyTag).hasClass('menu')) {
    $(logo).css({
         dislpay: 'table',
         margin: '0 auto'
    });
}
```

But I suggest to use css only for such a task.